# Can I make my program continue running even after I lock my screen?

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, suspend, cuda, gpu

I developed a program that needs to run for a long time (training an AI model). It works well, but the moment my screen get locked it stops with an error. The errors are multiple lines like those :

```
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1183] failed to enqueue async memcpy 
from host to device: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED: unspecified launch failure;
E tensorflow/stream_executor/stream.cc:334] Error recording event in stream: Error recording CUDA event: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED: unspecified launch failure; not marking stream as bad, as the Event object may be at fault. Monitor for further errors.
```

I don't think that's a CUDA error but more like the way Ubuntu normally works. However I would like my computer to continue the program even when I lock my screen. By the way, letting my computer unlocked is not a solution for me as I have sensitive data and can't let my computer open while I'm not here.

What should I do to solve this problem ?

Edit : I lock my screen using Super+L

Comment: a headless server perhaps? A possible solution here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268106/headless-ubuntu-setup-w-o-keyboard might need a bit of tweaking though to achieve what you want.

Comment: It seems your question isn't really about Ubuntu, but more about how computers work in general. A computer running unattended is referred to as a server. You can build a server out of everything, including an older laptop, and then install any OS and run any software you like.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I'll try to use a server then.

Comment: @ArturMeinild  It still is not normal that a program would stop just by locking the screen.

Comment: The title says "suspend". So it's not clear if it's a simple screen lock, or actually standby/suspend. And since we don't know the program, how should we be able to know how it behaves? All I can say is that an AI training model that stops working if you lock your screen is poorly written (and beyond the scope of this site).

Comment: @user68186 It's a desktop.

Comment: @ArturMeinild I'm sorry if I confuse the keywords, but typically what I do is locking my screen using Super+L, and I don't know the quality of the code since it's from Tensorflow (on python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue. I went to "Settings" -> "Power" and disabled "Automatic suspend". Apparently it automatically suspended my computer after some time when I was locking my screen.
Now I can lock my screen and my program continue running.